# Deploying reports from multiple parameters automatically?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm quite new to SSRS. I have a set of reports which obtain parameters from a query (defined as dataset in BIDS). These parameters include a machine identity, starting date and ending date. While each is specific to each machine, SSRS will put all parameters into separate drop-down lists which the user must then select the correct values from and run the report.

The problem, as you may imagine, is that there is somewhat of a wide margin for error here on the target user's part. The user is able to select incorrect starting and ending dates from this list for any machine. These reports should ideally run automatically on a schedule every Monday morning, but I'm having difficulty seeing how this is accomplished, as SSRS must essentially iterate through the machine ID list and use the appropriate starting and ending dates for each report. All other reports in this instance depend on these parameters which are gleaned from this query.

Does anyone know how to automatically run multiple SSRS reports based on a list of parameters? I sounds like some sort of coding logic is necessary here but I don't know how to use it in this case (I would prefer to have no user interaction, if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Data Drive Subscriptions?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169972.aspx

Comment: Yes, I've been looking into them, it seems like the way to go. Now of course I have another stumbling block: DateTime values, when passed from query to report as parameters during a schedule, seem to cause this error: ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportParameterTypeMismatchException: The value provided for the report parameter 'reportstartdate' is not valid for its type., ;
 Info: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportParameterTypeMismatchException: The value provided for the report parameter 'reportstartdate' is not valid for its type.

Comment: Here's a blog post that was made by someone with a similar problem. He talks about converting the database datetime field to a string. http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2011/06/value-provided-for-report-parameter.html